# Correct options given are A,D but why are B,C wrong?

Tags: functions

For every pair of continuous functions $f, g:[0, 1]\to R$ such that
$max {f(x) : x \in [0,1]} = max {g(x) : x \in[0, 1]}$,
the correct statement(s) is (are) :

(A) $(f(c))^2
+ 3f(c) = (g(c))^2
 + 3g(c)$ for some $c\in [0, 1]$

(B)$ (f(c))^2
 + f(c) = (g(c))^2
+ 3g(c) $ for some $c\in [0, 1]$

(C) $(f(c))^2
+ 3f(c) = (g(c))^2
+ g(c)$ for some $c \in [0, 1]$

(D) $(f(c))^2
 = (g(c))^2$
 for some $c \in [0, 1]$

Now ,if $f$ and $g$ can have value $0$ at some $c $, then $b$ and $c$ should also be correct. 
Please help me understand where i am making the mistake.

Comment: Why must $f,g$ have the value $0$ at some $c$?  Further, why must they have the value $0$ at the *same* $c$?

Comment: The question is asking which *must* be true ("For every pair..."), not which *might* be true.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=g(x)=1$ for all $x$ and both B and C are false.

When you think about A and D you need to think about how you prove they are true for every $f,g$ that satisfies the conditions.  I will just look at D.  We are given that $\max f(x)=\max g(x)$.  Since they are given as maximum, the values are attained.  Call this maximum $d$.  Then there is $y$ such that $f(y)=d$ and $z$ such that $g(z)=d$.  If $y=z$ we are done because we can take $c=y=z$.  Otherwise assume $y \lt z$ and consider $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$.  Because $f(y)$ is the maximum for $f$ and $g(z)$ is the equal maximum for $g$, $h(y) \gt 0$ and $h(z) \lt 0$.  Now use the intermediate value theorem to conclude there is a $c$ where $h(c)=0$